# Accessing props in User profile page and update the values on every form change

Tags: reactjs

I have the following data in redux.

[image]

This can be accessed using

```
this.props.user
```

I have a form where these data is displayed. These values can be changed and updated.

```
<Form>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="email">Email</Label>
            <Input type="email" name="email" value={this.props.user.email} disabled />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup>
            <Label for="first_name">First Name</Label>
            <Input type="text" name="first_name" value={this.props.user.first_name}  />
          </FormGroup>
...
</Form>
```

For this reason, **i am planning to use the value from props and assign the value to state object**.

The state now becomes

```
state = {
  user: {
    address: '',
    city: ''
  }
}
```

when the value is changed, the state will be updated using handleChange method and finally when the data is submitted the user object in state will contain all data(modified and non modified).

Question 1:
Is this the correct approach?

Question 2:
If values are to used directly from props, How do we handle every form change event?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: I assign props values related to forms to state like you've suggested for the same reason (props are immutable -- they can't be changed) and then having a change and submit handler manage the form and its state. I think this is pretty standard practice from what I've seen.

Answer 2: You don't use props for state management, only initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial state as the one coming from props like

```
state = {
  user: this.props.user
}
```

And then use the state as a value in input like

```
<Input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.user.email} disabled />
```

This way it will take the initial value from props & update every time when state changes